# Unable to find username and password fields for ASP.Net (not in webconfig)

Tags: asp.net, odbc

My office recently did some migration of servers, and as a result our webpages now use different data sources. For our environment, we typically use SQL Server, though we also have a linked server to an Oracle database. I am having difficulty finding out where I need to update the username and password for one of our web pages.

Generally speaking, the process has been pretty easy: go to Web.Config, find the connection string that the page is using, and update it with the relevant data source, username, and password. This page, however, is different. First, I get this error when visiting the page:

> ERROR [28000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password;
>   logon denied
>
> ERROR [IM006][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
>   SQLSetConnectAttr failed
>
> ERROR [28000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password;
>   login failed

Okay, so obviously I need to update the password somewhere. I go to Web.Config, and I don't see any connection strings. This is a first for me, so I start looking around, and the only thing I see (worth mentioning) is this line:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1; Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

To me, this indicates that the database is local, or at the very least my problem lies on the webserver itself. So I remote in, and I check both the ODBC connections for Oracle and SQL Server; no  issues. Each of them work. I even check the 32-bit and 64-bit connections.

Googling "Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed" tells me it's the ODBC issues, but again...I can't find anything.

Does anyone have any ideas on why I keep getting these errors and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I (well, technically my coworker) found the answer. The answer lied within IIS. Basically, we were missing two connection strings. The first one references the driver, and the second one (I believe) contains the username/password that is passed to the ODBC driver through the first connection string. Whereas normally the connection strings are stored in the program (web.config file), in this case it was on the actual server. The program looked for the connection strings there, but couldn't find it.